# when i using the client of GitHub i get a error:System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: github, http-status-code-407

```
2017-07-02 17:37:51.8708|INFO|thread: 5|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Released concurrent scheduler for operation: 10 at GitClient.cs:290 after blocking 0.4168211s
2017-07-02 17:37:52.2268|INFO|thread: 1|ObservableEx|Could not refresh repository information from API failed.
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Octokit.Internal.HttpClientAdapter.<Send>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Octokit.Connection.<RunRequest>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Octokit.Connection.<Run>d__23`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Octokit.ApiConnection.<Get>d__0`1.MoveNext()
2017-07-02 17:37:52.2318|INFO|thread: 1|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Acquiring concurrent scheduler for operation 12 at BranchesViewModel.cs:356
2017-07-02 17:37:52.2318|INFO|thread: 4|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Acquired concurrent scheduler for operation: 12 at BranchesViewModel.cs:356 after waiting 6.27E-05s
2017-07-02 17:37:52.2318|INFO|thread: 1|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Acquiring concurrent scheduler for operation 13 at RepositoryViewModel.cs:318
2017-07-02 17:37:52.2318|INFO|thread:14|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Acquired concurrent scheduler for operation: 13 at RepositoryViewModel.cs:318 after waiting 6.9E-05s
2017-07-02 17:37:52.2548|INFO|thread: 5|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Released concurrent scheduler for operation: 12 at BranchesViewModel.cs:356 after blocking 0.0226196s
2017-07-02 17:37:52.2758|INFO|thread: 1|NewPullRequestViewModel|No matching pull request found, clearing selection...
```

Answer (score 0):

What operation did you make before you get this Error?
I guess something goes wrong with your config file.
Check your username,password,port,and so on.(use git config --list)